# Error filling print, com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException:

Tags: mongodb, jasper-reports, mongodb-query, jaspersoft-studio

I am newbie in Jasper Studio. I am using "iReport 5.5.0". I've created a datasource named as "MyMongoDB" in iReport. Now in a report query, I give following query, where contact is a collection name

```
db.contact.find()
```

Could anyone please guide me? .

Which one is better to developed Reports iReport or Studio? I need to developed application which uses Spring MVC and MongoDB

```
Error filling print...  db.contact.find(); ^ 
    com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException:  db.contact.find(); ^ 
        at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parse(JSON.java:381)      
        at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parse(JSON.java:328)      
        at com.mongodb.util.JSON.parse(JSON.java:287)      
        at com.mongodb.util.JSON.parse(JSON.java:272)      
        at com.jaspersoft.mongodb.query.MongoDbQueryWrapper.processQuery(MongoDbQueryWrapper.java:104)      
        at com.jaspersoft.mongodb.query.MongoDbQueryWrapper.<init>(MongoDbQueryWrapper.java:93)     
        at com.jaspersoft.mongodb.query.MongoDbQueryExecuter.createDatasource(MongoDbQueryExecuter.java:117)      
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.createQueryDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:1112)      
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.initDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:689)      
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.setParameters(JRBaseFiller.java:1281)      
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:900)      
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:845)      
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:87)      
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:446)      
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:276)      
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:745)      
        at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.IReportCompiler.run(IReportCompiler.java:891)      
        at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572)      
        at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997)  
    Print not filled. Try to use an EmptyDataSource...
```

Answer (score 0):

Jasper Studio is best way to create Jasper reports.

try with this,

```
 { collectionName : 'collection name'}
```

try with this link, it will provide examples how write mongodb query with Jasper reports
[Jaspersoft MongoDB Query Language](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/jaspersoft-mongodb-query-language)